# Missin template on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

I have this two methods on `catalog_controler.rb`

```
  def latest
   @boxes = Box.latest  5
   @page_title = 'Novedades'
  end

def rss
 latest
 render :layout => false
end
```

end
on app/views/catalog folder I have this xml file , `rss.xml.erb`

```
xml.instruct! :xml, :version=>"1.0", :encoding=>"UTF-8"
xml.rss("version" => "2.0", "xmlns:dc" => "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/") do
xml.channel do
xml.title @page_title
xml.link(url_for(:action => "index", :only_path => false))
xml.language "en-us"
xml.ttl "40"
xml.description "International Boxes"
 for book in @books
  xml.item do
  xml.title(book.title)
  xml.description("#{box.model})
  xml.pubDate(book.created_at.to_s(:long))
  xml.guid(url_for(:action => "show", :id => book, :only_path => false))
  xml.link(url_for(:action => "show", :id => book, :only_path => false))
end
end
end
end
```

But it gives an missing template error:

```
Missing template catalog/rss, application/rss with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html],     :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/user/desktop/eshop_con_CSS/app/views"
```

How can I show the xml file on browser?

Answer (score 0):

Read about [**MimeResponds**](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to)'s `respond_to` method. It should look like below, please change the block content as per your requirement.

```
def rss
  @latest = latest
  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml { render xml: @latest }
  end
end
```

`respond_to` can adopt to various different *MIMES* including popular `.json`, which is very handy in building/working-with APIs.